# Attachments not sending when emailing a contact in CiviCRM v. 4.7.10

Tags: contacts, email, attachments

When sending an email to a contact, the email sends OK, but without the attachment. I can see from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8853) that this is a known bug in 4.7.10, and a simple fix has been provided, which will be implemented in 4.7.11. I made the fix in 4.7.10, but it doesn't work - emails still send without the attachments. Until 4.7.11 is released, does anyone know how to make 4.7.10 work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please ignore what I wrote. The fix does work. I just fixed the wrong installation. What a dork. All sorted now.